# Java: Splitting string variable into a string and integer variables?

Tags: java, string, variables, split, integer

I have looked everywhere but can seem to find a solution. Is it possible to separate a string variable such as "A1" into a string "A" and integer 1 variables?

Comment: Besides looking everywhere, did you attempt this yourself?

Comment: no. we won't make your homework

Comment: Answers to your questions yes i did attempt it myself but as am relatively new to java it was something i hadn't come across. I had Googled/Youtubed it but couldn't find the tiny bit of code to help me anywhere. It was't homework, I'm too old for homework I'm just keen to learning all aspects of the language and all the little tricks that can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Start parsing from 0 if you see non digit keep adding it to a StringBuffer, as you see digit add the content of StringBuffer to `List<String> strings;` and same for Digits `List<String> numbers`

Answer (score 0):

If the string length is strictly **one letter** and the number is only **1 digit**, you can use `String.split("")`, however for a more generic solution you can use `regex`

Sample Code:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)").matcher("variable1121");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " , " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
variable , 1121
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string variable such as `A1` or `ABC123`, you can try:

```
String input = "A1";
String[] array = input.split("(?<=([a-zA-Z]++))");

String str = array[0];
int integer = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
```